# mysql complex select query

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have 4 tables:

```
user,
administrative_division,
assignment,
user_has_assignment
```

Between user and administrative_division there is a many-to-one relationship where many is user and one is administrative_division. Between user and assignment there is a many-to-many relationship through the user_has_assignment table.

I can get how many users are in each administrative_division by using this command:

```
select division_id, count(*) from user group by division_id;
```

Which, for example, gives me something like this:

```
division_id count(*)
  1           4
  2           10
```

etc.

I can get how many assignments are owned by each user by using this command:

```
select user_id, count(*) from user_has_assignment group by user_id;
```

which gives similar result

```
user_id count(*)
   1       2
   2       10
```

But I don't know how I can get in one query a result like this:

```
division_id  user_count assignment_count
     1           10            20 
     2            2            4
```

where user_count is the total number of users in each administrative_division and assignment_count is the total of all assignments owned by users from one particular administrative_division.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you have two users in a division with the same assignment? Would that add 1 or 2 to the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply need to join the tables above and group the results by the devision_id, so you would get a single row per devision like so:

```
SELECT ad.devision_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) AS user_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.assignment_id) AS assignment_count
FROM user u
     JOIN administrative_division ad ON u.devision_id = ad.devision_id
     LEFT JOIN user_has_assignment ucon ON u.user_id = ucon.user_id
     LEFT JOIN assignment a ON a.assignment_id = ucon.assignment_id
```

check the field names in the query and replace them accordingly in order for the query to work on your schema.

Comment: @Nurzhan : no problem at all - if your question was answered, make sure to check the correct answer to help other people who may encounter a similar issue

Comment: @Nurzhan, I don't think this will add 2 to the count if two users in a division have the same assignment.